# How does Hulu transition their pages?

Tags: jquery, transition, page-refresh

I was wondering how Hulu transitions their pages, when clicking between links? The page does not seem to indicate a page refresh or redirect.

Could something like that be accomplished with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why yes, yes you can!

see here

http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/02/23/how-to-use-jquery-to-make-slick-page-transitions/